# BorgBackup: fuse: failed to exec fusermount3: No such file or directory

Tags: fuse, borgbackup

I'm trying to run the `borg mount` in Borg Backup, but it's saying that `fusermount3` is not installed.

```
fuse: failed to exec fusermount3: No such file or directory
```

Googling this problem isn't helping. I have fuse installed:

```
fuse is already the newest version (2.9.9-3).
```

as is libfuse:

```
libfuse2 is already the newest version (2.9.9-3).
```

I'm running Linux Mint 20 with Kernel 5.4.0-113-generic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out: I had to install `fuse3`

```
sudo apt-get install fuse3
```